# Задание кодировки при создании файла

Tags: python, кодировка

Cоздаю файл самым простым способом

```
open("file.txt" , "w")
```

А можно как-нибудь указать кодировку? Допустим, хочу поставить utf-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте стандартный модуль [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html), в нем для функции open можно задать кодировку.

Answer (score 3):

Вам не файлу указывать кодировку надо, а просто писать в файл с нужной кодировкой, и соответственно читать потом с той кодировкой, которой писал.

```
f = open("file.txt","w")  
f.write(u"Hello, ")  
f.write(unicode("World!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать файл с кодировкой utf-8:

```
f = open("name","w", encoding="utf-8")
```

При открытии тоже нужно будет указать кодировку:

```
f = open("name","r", encoding="utf-8")
```